# Learning rate not set in run_mlm.py?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I want to run (or resume) the `run_mlm.py` script with a specific learning rate, but it doesn't seem like setting it in the script arguments does anything.

```
os.system(
    f"python {script} \
        --model_type {model} \
        --config_name './models/{model}/config.json' \
        --train_file './content/{data}/train.txt' \
        --validation_file './content/{data}/test.txt' \
        --learning_rate 6e-4 \
        --weight_decay 0.01 \
        --warmup_steps 6000 \
        --adam_beta1 0.9 \
        --adam_beta2 0.98 \
        --adam_epsilon 1e-6 \
        --tokenizer_name './tokenizer/{model}' \
        --output_dir './{out_dir}' \
        --do_train \
        --do_eval \
        --num_train_epochs 40 \
        --overwrite_output_dir {overwrite} \
        --ignore_data_skip"
)
```

After warm-up, the log indicates that the learning rate tops out at 1e-05—a default from somewhere, I guess, but I'm not sure where (and certainly not 6e-4):

`{'loss': 3.9821, 'learning_rate': 1e-05, 'epoch': 0.09}`

Comment: Which version of transformers are you using? Have you considered removing Adam-specific configurations, since I believe this can also change learning rates (AFAIK)? Have you tried setting a constant lr_scheduler (instead of the default, which is linear decay)?

Comment: I'm on 4.12.0.dev0. Honestly, I only recently started using `run_mlm.py`, because I was having a hard time getting the Datasets api to work with my previous scripts. I wanted to move to Datasets because `LineByLineTextDataset` was taking around 30 mins to load my full dataset. In my earlier script I'd found that the original RoBERTa-base parameters worked well, so that's why I wanted to try them here. I do get okay results with whatever `run_mlm.py` does on its own, but I wanted to try what had previously performed well. I'll try removing the Adam parameters, thanks.